# Do adverts break NC clause of Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International (CC BY-NC-ND 4.0) licence

Tags: non-commercial, cc-by-nc-nd

I have an idea for an android app and I'm interested if it is legal.

Basically there are sites where people upload their recipes for vape juices, and all of these recipes fall under this specific licence.

What I'm trying to do is to create an app that collects all of these recipes. Sort of an archive, and it would also have a calculator for quick mixing. Later on I would add possibility of user creating accounts and adding new recipes etc.

My question is, is this legal if I give the appropriate credits to each recipe? And could I put adverts on the app or would this fall under commercial use? Also what if some functions of the app would cost money(this would not hide any recipes behind this "paywall") such as users adding new recipes?

Comment: CC NC licences are not Free or Open Source.

Answer (score 3):

It's OK, if you don't sell the app, have no ads and no premium content or in - app purchases.

If you do either of the above, it is quite clearly a commercial use: you use it to generate profit in terms of ad revenue or using them as means to direct users to"premium content" or by selling the app.

When it comes to the 'no commercial' clause : The way on how to use the work for your profit is irrelevant, only the fact that you do.

The exact line between commercial and non - commercial usage is drawn by the courts and thus depends on jurisdiction. E.g. see this video podcast from one of Germany's well - known lawers in media laws, citing a ruling that usage on a website of a public radio station is illegal and awarded damages to the creator of the CC-NC - licensed content: https://youtu.be/Ejy9U9Df_gU

That said I am reasonably confident that the ruling will go this way often in other jurisdictions, too, as the intent of the license is to prevent other people from taking commercial advantage of the work - in whatever form.